# How to add headers from lookup table when using separate_header function which created multiple column headers

Tags: r, lookup-tables, flextable

I have a dataframe which I am wrangling into a cross-tab like table using flextable package. I append the pivoted column names using ".." which is then used with the seperate_header function to create layered column headers. Here is a reproducible example of the table used to create the formattable table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Creating a sample dataframe similar to table4
data <- data.frame(
  PM_Month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb"),
  reachable = c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no"),
  reason_unreachable = c("Reason 1", "Reason 2", "Reason 1", "Reason 2", "Reason 3")
)

tabledat <- data %>%
  filter(reachable == "no") %>%
  group_by(PM_Month, reason_unreachable) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(pct = prop.table(n) * 100) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(PM_Month),
    names_from = reason_unreachable,
    names_glue = "{reason_unreachable}..{.value}",
    values_from = c(n, pct)
  ) %>%
  select(c(PM_Month), sort(names(.))) %>%
  mutate(TOTAL = rowSums(across(ends_with("..n"), .names = "sum_{.col}"), na.rm = TRUE))
```

but I then want to replace the answer options for "reason_unreachable" which are now the spanning column headers (but there are two spanning col headers now), using a look- up table and the set_header_df function but I cannot specify which column headers to be set.

```
#look up table
lookup_table <- data.frame(
  key = c("Reason 1", "Reason 2", "Reason 3"),
  label = c("Not Home", "Passed Away", "At work")
)
flextable(tabledat) %>%
  separate_header(split="\\.{2}")%>%
set_header_df(mapping = lookup_table, key = "key")
```

I was expecting an output table which has the column header row values replaced with the corresponding values in the look up table but instead the output is blank headers all together. Hoping to create a function incorporating this functionality for a big survey dataset, any insights are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work because `set_header_df` make changes in the original data frame names of `tabledata` ("PM_Month", "Reason 1..n", "Reason 1..pct", ...).

One way of doing what you want is using a named vector and the `labellizor` function:

```r
lookup_table <- data.frame(
  key = c("Reason 1", "Reason 2", "Reason 3"),
  label = c("Not Home", "Passed Away", "At work")
)

lookup_vector <- setNames(lookup_table$label,lookup_table$key)

flextable(tabledat) %>%
  separate_header(split="\\.{2}") %>% 
  labelizor(labels = lookup_vector, part = "header")
```

[image]

Comment: What a useful function, this works perfectly. Thank you for your elegant and timely response!